# Store Array into variable

Tags: mysql, arrays, list, variables

This is what I am trying but it is not working.

```
SET @myArray = "25,21,90";

SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE bField IN (@myArray);
```

I end up getting only the results where bField = 25.

Obviously I am asking this because I have a more complex script than the example above. The @myArray may be used multiple times or buried deap in a longer statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [Find_In_Set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
select * from aTable where FIND_IN_SET(bField, @myArray);
```